# Unable to Implement Sequential execution of Spark Functions

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In our Spark Pipeline we read messages from kafka.

```
JavaPairDStream<byte[],byte[]> = messagesKafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext, byte[].class, byte[].class,DefaultDecoder.class,DefaultDecoder.class,
                configMap,topic,StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER());
```

We transform these messages using a map function.

```
JavaDStream<ProcessedData> lines=messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<byte[],byte[]>, ProcessedData>() 
        {
          public ProcessedData  call(Tuple2<byte[],byte[]> tuple2) 
            {


            }
        });
```

//Here ProcessedData is my message bean class.

After this we save this message into Cassandra using foreachRDD function.And then we index the same message in ElasticSearch using foreachRDD function.What we require is that first the message gets stored in cassandra and it executes successfully then only it is indexed in ElasticSearch.To achieve this we require sequential execution of Cassandra and Elastic Search functions.

We are not able to generate a JavaDStream within the foreachRDD function of Cassandra to be given as input to ElasticSearch Function.

We can successfully execute the sequential execution of Cassandra and Elastic Search functions if we use map functions inside them.But then there is no Action in our Spark Pipeline and it is not executed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you added the full flow of your job to the code sample. It's hard to follow what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this sequencing would be to put the Cassandra insert and the ElasticSearch indexing within the same task.
Roughly something like this (*):

```
val kafkaDStream = ???
val processedData = kafkaDStream.map(elem => ProcessData(elem))
val cassandraConnector = CassandraConnector(sparkConf)
processData.forEachRDD{rdd =>
    rdd.forEachPartition{partition => 
        val elasClient = ??? elasticSearch client instance
        partition.foreach{elem => 
            cassandraConnector.withSessionDo(session =>
                 session.execute("INSERT ....")
            }
            elasClient.index(elem) // whatever the client method is called
        }
     }
}
```

We sacrifice the capability of batching operations (done internally by the Cassandra-spark connector for example) in order to implement sequencing.

(*) The structure of the Java version of this code is very similar, just more verbose.